# Scripts and Styles file Sequences

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, css

I am developing an app in asp.net webforms. Vertical Scroll is not working on page and I am including the files in this sequence

```
script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/bootstrap.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/scripts.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>


     <script src="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/Validations/common.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/Validations/constants.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/Validations/masking.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/Validations/validator.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/Validations/Validations.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/script.js") %>" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/coolclock.js") %>" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/moreskins.js") %>" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/excanvas.js") %>" ></script>
  <%--<script src="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery.js") %>" type="text/javascript" ></script>--%>
     <script src="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery.innerfade.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jqueryscripts.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/ts_picker.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>


      <link href="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Styles/bootstrap.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Styles/bootstrap-responsive.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <link href="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Styles/bootstrap.min.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Styles/main.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700' rel='stylesheet'
        type='text/css'>
```

Tell me the problem is related to file sequence or someone else.

Comment: The problem is related to file sequence or someone else.

Comment: Do you have any errors in the browser console?

Comment: If vertical scroll isn't working ... Why do you think is a problem in the file sequences?. Probably one property in the body like `overflow:hidden`

Comment: Perhaps remove and add them one by one to at least narrow down what might be causing the issue. There are a lot of frameworks in there!